# JavaScript - "this" doesn't work when calling Promises instead of functions

Tags: javascript, function, this, promise

So, I recently had a pretty weird problem when developing a library, [safe_children](https://github.com/oratio-io/safe_children).

When I was writing the examples, I decided to try making it like this:

```
var child = new Child('otherFile.js', 3 * 60);
child.loadScript()
  .then(child.spawn);
```

This code doesn't work. `this` points to something I couldn't find out. However, this piece of code works:

```
var child = new Child('otherFile.js', 3 * 60);
child.loadScript()
  .then(function(){
    child.spawn();
  });
```

Anyone knows why? What is `this` in this context? Thanks!

Comment: `console.log(this)` and find out - `.then(function() { console.log(this); })`

Comment: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/README.md#you-dont-know-js-scope--closures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue here has nothing to do with promises.

You are passing in `child.spawn`, which is nothing more than a function. Your promise has no way to know that it belongs to `child`, so all it can do is call it. Therefore, `this` will most likely either be `null`, `undefined`, or the `window` object.

You can see the same behavior by doing:

```
var sp = child.spawn;
sp();    // <---- `this` is not `child` here
```

You can get around this by doing:

```
.then(child.spawn.bind(child));
```

or by doing what you've already done.

Comment: Thanks! Fixing my documentation...